# SSH (with Putty) to local VM on host that has VPN on

Tags: vpn, home-networking, vmware-player

I'm trying to access with Putty to my local Linux VM (using VMware player) on a host that has (commercial) VPN on. I'm able to connect to the guest machine with host-only network adapter but I don't have internet connection on the guest machine. If I switch to NAT, I get network error. And Bridged network is not an option as I don't want the machine to be exposed to the network. Any help is greatly appreciated.

In short: I want to be able to SSH to my local VM with VPN on on the host. Also the guest machine needs to have internet access.

Comment: It's a terrible commercial VPN if it routes traffics to private IPs that it is not using into the tunnel. See if the subnet it uses conflicts with the one you use, maybe. Also options to make exception or so.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's an easy fix. I just changed the default gateway (which was empty) and (just in case) the dns also of the virtual network adapter used by vmware player. The problem was that the machines couldn't find each other because they weren't in the same network, in this case the host was not connected to the virtual network the guest machine was connected to.